# Finding the last row of a Pandas data frame containing Data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This may be a relatively amateur question, but how do I find the last row of a pandas dataframe containing data in python?

I have a poorly structured spreadsheet I am trying to read in and manipulate, but the doc has an excessive number of extra cells below the end of the actual data.

Comment: [pandas.DataFrame.last_valid_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.last_valid_index.html) ?

Comment: `df.iloc[df.last_valid_index()]` assuming `df` is the dataframe containing the data.

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you.